# Repeated query takes long time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 standard edition and working on the performance tuning of application.

If I execute the same query multiple times, the execution time increases every time till it comes back to almost normal. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE emp_name = 'sam'
```

---

```
| first time | 9 sec  |
| 2nd time   | 18 sec |
| 3rd time   | 29 sec |
| 4th time   | 10 sec |
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are optimizing an application so i guess you can find the reason of the issue there. Have you tried to execute this query in SSMS?

Comment: How big is your employees table? I wouldn't expect 9 seconds on a simple query like that. Can you try putting an index on the emp_name column?

Comment: If it is a live database, the same table may be being accessed by other processes or the server could be busy dealing with other requests, varying the execution time. If the execution plan and costs are the same but the times vary, this will be the case.

Comment: That could be caused by many things. Most likely query plan can't change. Your data could drop out of buffer pool (=cache) or you could be experiencing blocking, or other processes might get priority over you etc. You need to look into the server what's happening and for example use `set statistics io on` on see if the I/O counts are the same for each run.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your query:

```
Select *
from dbo.Employee
where emp_name = 'sam';
```

Then you want an index on `Employee(emp_name)` or a compound index where `emp_name` is the first column.

Under most circumstances, such a query should not be taking multiple seconds -- unless you have lots of Sam's, the columns are particularly wide, or the "table" is really a view.